# Обращение к левому объекту в перегрузке

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Недавно начал изучать перегрузку операторов. Пытаюсь перегрузить оператор `*` как пересечение множеств, но не могу понять как в данном случае обратиться к левому объекту.

```
template <class T>
class Set
{
public:
T ch;
set <T> cs; //создаем множество

Set()
{
    int n;
    T temp;
    cout << "Количество элементов множества";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        cs.insert(temp);
    }
}

template <class T>void operator * (Set <T> second)
{
    //Как обратиться к first?
    second.Print();
}

void Print()
{
    set <T>::iterator ik;
    for (ik = cs.begin(); ik != cs.end(); ++ik)
        cout << *ik << "  ";
    cout << endl;
}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru");
Set<char>first;
first.Print();

first = first + 'd';
first.Print();

Set<char>second;
second.Print();

first*second;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указатель на него - `this`, ссылка - `*this`...

Это же просто ваш объект, членом которого является оператор.

И еще - скажите, а где вы намерены хранить результат пересечения множеств? Ваш оператор не возвращает ничего, так что у вас возможна просто запись

```
Set1 * Set2;
```

И где будет пересечение - в `Set1` или в `Set2`?
Кстати, поскольку у вас оператор получает объект по значению, `Set2` просто копируется. Это вам точно надо?

Может, логичнее было бы

```
Set operator*(const Set& s1, const Set& s2)
```

Именно так - не член класса, а свободная функция? (шаблонность для краткости я опустил)

Опять же, вы так вольно обошлись с шаблоном внутри шаблона, что не удивлюсь, если вы вскоре будете задавать новые вопросы по поводу вашего кода...

Comment: ну если попытаться вывести его в перегрузке "this.Print();", то выдает ошибку выражение слева от ".Print" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение

Comment: Конечно. Ведь я же написал - `this` - это **указатель**! Прочтите первую строку ответа. Так что - или `this->Print()`, или `(*this).Print()`...

Answer (score 1):

Имеется несколько способов. Во-первых, вы можете вызвать функцию-член класса, используя неквалифицированное имя. Например,

```
Print();
```

Во-вторых, вы можете использовать указатель this. Например,

```
this->Print();
```

Имейте в виду, что возвращаемый тип оператора * `void` не имеет смысла. Так как этот оператор вы хотите перегрузить для операции пересечения множеств, то он должен возвращать множество, соответствующее пересечению.